# DropdownButtonFormField and `alignedDropdown` property

Tags: flutter

I used DropdownButtonFormField in my form. Also I wanted its width in expanded view to be the same as the dropdown button width, so I've wrapped it in `ButtonTheme` and set the `alignedDropdown: true`.

But this resulted in one side effect which I don't know how to correct now: it added an extra left padding for the hint text as shown in the screenshot below. Could you advice how to fix this?
If I remove the `ButtonTheme` then the hint padding is the same as labels in other form field but then my dropdown's width does not suit me.
[image]

Source:

```
Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    Flexible(
      flex: 4,
      child: ButtonTheme(
        alignedDropdown: true,
        child: DropdownButtonFormField(
          items: phoneTypeMenuItems(),
          hint: Text('Phone type'),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    SizedBox(width:16),
    Flexible(
      child: TextFormField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: "Phone", 
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.
          symmetric(vertical: 4)
        ),
        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
        inputFormatters: [
          WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly, 
          LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(10), 
          BlacklistingTextInputFormatter.singleLineFormatter],
      ),
      flex: 5,
    )
  ],
),
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `ButtonTheme` should be a child of `DropdownButtonFormField` not the other way around.

Comment: not sure why you think so. As far as I can see `DropdownButtonFormField` has no `child` field...

Comment: You are right, it doesn't. I mistook it for `DropdownButtonHideUnderline` which is what I use on my code with `ButtonTheme` as its child. It works like you want yours to work when I set `alignedDropdown: true`.

Comment: I know about `DropdownButtonHideUnderline`. If you look the sources of `DropdownButtonFormField` you will see that there's already a `DropdownButtonHideUnderline` baked inside it.